# Apache: Serving content from two different locations and ports

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have an Apache server running on Ubuntu 14 on a server on which I have sudo.

When users request the server's IP, Apache serves content from `/var/www/html`.

I'd like to keep this behavior intact, and make it so that users who request IP/cats get some special content that's hosted by a Docker container on port 7777.

What's the best way to achieve this functionality in Apache?

Comment: If you already have the container up, then using the apache server's proxy module is easiest.

Comment: @arkascha thanks very much! That works quite nicely. I have one quick follow-up if you have a second. I made `/etc/apache2/sites-available/cats.com` and tried to set up the reverse proxy there, but it didn't take. I could only get the reverse proxy to run if I modified `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. Do you know how I can ensure the former file is interpreted?

Comment: Sounds like you are on some debian flavor. With that setup you need to symlink the entry in sites-available to sites-enabled and restart the http server process to enable the additional virtual host.

Comment: @arkascha interesting, that's what I thought. I tried `sudo a2ensite IP.conf` and then `sudo service apache2 reload` and `sudo service apache2 restart` but no luck yet...

Comment: You cannot have two IP based virtual hosts defined that way. Does not make much sense. You need to use name based virtual hosts. Offers much more flexibility anyway.

Comment: To put it another way, ``VirtualHost`` definitions are not merged. If for same IP or virtual host and port you need different handlers, they must be in the same ``VirtualHost`` definition. So stick it all in the default ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: @arkascha amen, thanks very much. It doesn't seem the conf file needs to be a host configured with the server DNS in any way. I used a more interpretable host filename for the conf file in the end, though also needed to delete `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

Comment: @arkascha and GrahamDumpleton thanks very much for your notes! If you have thoughts on my workaround below, I'd be very grateful for your input!

Comment: All this has nothing to do with DNS. You only need to be able to resolve that host locally, so by means of a hosts file for example. You do not need to disable or delete the default host, actually the apache http server will _always_ operate some default host, always the first host defined by the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @arkascha I did the following to get this going:

Create a file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wow.conf` with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  # enable proxies
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /cats http://0.0.0.0:7777/
  ProxyPassReverse /cats http://0.0.0.0:7777/

  ServerAdmin douglas.duhaime@yale.edu
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This says when requests come in for IP/cats, serve the users the content from port 7777.

I then symlinked this file to the sites-enabled directory:

```
sudo ln /etc/apache2/sites-available/wow.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wow.conf
```

Finally, I needed to delete the default sites enabled file and restart the server:

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

P.S. Apache is amazing.